# Google Maps - Animation

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've been working with the Google Maps API all day. I can pull in all my markers and drop custom icons on about 50 points. However, I can't set an interaval for the marker drops. What am I doing wrong?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Golf</title>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"
            type="text/javascript"></script>

<style type="text/css">

.mapInfo {
  font-size:12px; 
  text-transform:capitalize;
}

</style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[ 


    function load() {

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.449799, -86.241248),
        zoom: 9,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      downloadUrl("golf-xml.php", function(data) {

        var xml = data.responseXML;

        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          //var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("value");
          var value = markers[i].getAttribute("value");
          var town = markers[i].getAttribute("town");


          //var erase = markers[i].getAttribute("erase");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          //var html = "<span class='mapInfo'><b>Address:</b> " + address + ", " + town + "<br/><b>Price:</b> " + value + "</span>";
          var html = "<span class='mapInfo'><b>Price:</b> " + value + "<br/><b>Address:</b> " + address + ", " + town + "</span>";

          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
          //alert (point);



          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: '1364428325_golf.png',
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            shadow: icon.shadow
          });

          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }


      });
    }

    function drop() {
      for (var i =0; i < point.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          marker();
        }, i * 200);
      }
    }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}



    //]]>
  </script>


  </head>

  <body onLoad="load()" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;" >
  <div class="land"><span class="land">Copy</span>
      <br />
  </div>
    <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 620px"></div>



  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this... (change the marker icon path in line 34)

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        html {
          height: 100%
        }
        body {
          height: 100%;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0
        }
        #map_canvas {
          height: 100%
        }
     </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBdTuWJjEUMvQZ6VVPGksE12XNgQgs__Qk&sensor=false&libraries=visualization"></script>
    <script language="javascript">

   var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.7833, 5.2167);
   var markersArray = [
            new google.maps.LatLng(20.11, 73.06),
            new google.maps.LatLng(10.11, 77.18),
            new google.maps.LatLng(33.11, 75.18),
            new google.maps.LatLng(25.11, 77.18),
                    new google.maps.LatLng(31.37, 74.55),
                    new google.maps.LatLng(22.56, 88.36),
                    new google.maps.LatLng(12.98, 77.58) 
                 ];

   var markers = [];
   var iterator = 0;
   var map; 
   var image = '/home/aravi/heatmap/gdot.png' ;


  function drop() {
             for ( i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++) 
              {
                    setTimeout(function() 
                 {
                   addMarker();
                 }, i*300);
              }
              }

  function addMarker() {

    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
      position: markersArray[iterator],
      map: map,
      draggable: false,
      opacity: 0.5,
     // animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      icon: image
    }));
    iterator++;
      }
function view() {
              var styles = [
    {
      stylers: [
      { hue: "#e0e0e0" },
      { saturation: -100 },
      {invert_lightness: false}
      ]
    },{
      featureType: "all",
      elementType: "geometry.fill",
      stylers: [
        { visibility: "on" }
      ]
    }
      ];
        var mapOptions = {
                   zoom:2,
                   center: myLatlng,    
                   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 
                               opacity: 0.2,
                               draggable: false,
                   disableDefaultUI: true,
                   styles: styles
                     };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

        drop ();    
}
</script>

</head>
<body onLoad="view()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:53%; height:70%; margin-left: 500px; margin-top: 38px;"> </div>       
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That works well, but how do I get items from an xml into the markersArray. Here is where I'm adding te XML. downloadUrl("golf-xml.php", function(data) {

      var markers = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {


        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                                    parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));

        var marker = createMarker(markers[i].getAttribute("address"), latlng);

       //alert (latlng);

       }
     });

Comment: I think the problem in your code is in the marker function you are calling inside setTimeout. I couldnt see any function marker()  declared in your code. Only an array marker is defined which pushes the markers inside the array.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in a separate `function` e.g `addMarker()`

```
function addMarker()
{
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
map: map,
position: point,
icon: '1364428325_golf.png',
animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
shadow: icon.shadow
});
}
```

Then call `addMarker()` within your `setTimeout()` function

as in you code i cant see the method marker() you described within you setTimeOut()

You can always visit https://gist.github.com/donpaul120/dc97f4ec4785521b3a66 and implement it.

I hope this Helps...